# Disable a button on the first row- AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I disable a button on a specific row say first row? I am trying to display details in the table depending on the CURRENT USER's ROLE. For eg- I disable the edit and delete buttons for all the rows if its a supplier or buyer-user.

Similarly, how do I disable ONLY the DELETE button of the FIRST row if a SUPER-ADMIN uses it. Because the first row contains the details of a super-Admin. He shouldn't delete himself right. :p

Thanks in advance.

```js
$scope.checkRole = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {

        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        console.log("Received", currentUser);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not received");
    }

    if (currentUser[0].role == "Supplier-User" || currentUser[0].role == "Buyer-User") { 
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    //if (currentUser[0].role == "Super-Admin") {
        //What should I type here?
    //}
};
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table100-head">
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-if="showUser(user)" ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUsers track by $index">
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.contact}}</td>
            <td>{{user.role}}</td>
            <td>{{user.company}}</td>
            <td>
                <button ng-disabled="checkRole()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#myModalEdit"
                        ng-click="selectUser(user)">
                  Edit
               </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button ng-disabled="checkRole()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#myModalDelete"
                        ng-click="selectUser(user)">
                  Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe try with `ng-if`
<button ng-if="currentUser.role === "Super-Admin"">Delete</button>

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$index` and the iterator as arguments to the disable functions:

```
<tr ng-show="showUser(user)" ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUsers"
   <td>
        <button ng-disabled="::disableEdit(user,$index)" type="button"
                class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModalEdit"
                ng-click="editUser(user)">
          Edit
       </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button ng-disabled="::disableDelete(user,$index)" type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#myModalDelete"
                ng-click="deleteUser(user)">
          Delete
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Note the use of the [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) operator (`::`) added to improve performance.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - special properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview).

Comment: hi your code is looking good .Just check the return value of $scope.checkRole